# Dynamic File Assignment with embedded space in filename

Tags: cobol, microfocus

I'm working under Microfocus Native cobol, and I want to create a Dynamic file name.

My Declaration is :

```
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT OUT-FILE ASSIGN TO DYNAMIC OUT-NAME
           ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
```

Then I read the file name from another file and place it into my `OUT-NAME`
and I create a file as:

```
OPEN OUTPUT OUT-FILE.
    write OUT-RECORD.
CLOSE OUT-FILE.
```

This works fine when I have no spaces in the filename.
But when I do, filename stops at the space

As an example we move a string into `OUT-NAME`

```
MOVE "C:\New Folder\Example.txt" INTO OUT-NAME
```

This creates a file in `C:\` named `New`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using Windows, and I just forgot to use backslash in the below example, I edited my question

Comment: @BillWoodger I found no solution to my problem. I tried to contact Microfocus, but they are asking so many questions, they want to make sure that I have the full edition before providing help, which I have, but I can't prove

Comment: Have you tried quoting the filename eg:
 MOVE '"C:\New Folder\Example.txt" INTO OUT-NAME"'
(note: the single quotes with a double quotes inside it)

Comment: @StephenGennard it works, thank you so much, I would never thought about that.

Comment: the answer was posted, thank You

Comment: OK, thanks, tidying away the comments a bit then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments By Stephen Gennard the answer is to use double quotes inside single quotes

```
MOVE '"C:\New Folder\Example.txt"' INTO OUT-NAME
```